# Does the field norm commute with field morphisms?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Consider a field extension $K$ of $\Bbb{Q}$, a finite extension $L$ of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ for some fixed prime number $p$, and a field morphism $\sigma \colon K \to L$ such that the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    K @>\sigma>> L\\
    @AAA @AAA\\
    \Bbb{Q} @>>\iota> \Bbb{Q}_p
\end{CD}
commutes. Is it true that
$$
N_{L/\Bbb{Q}_p}(\sigma(x)) = \iota(N_{K/\Bbb{Q}}(x)) = N_{K/\Bbb{Q}}(x)
$$
for every $x \in K$, where $N_{E/F}$ denotes the [field norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm) of a field extension $E/F$?

---

**Edit:** Álvaro Lozano-Robledo showed that the above statement is way too optimistic. Can it be fixed in the following way:
$$
N_{L/\Bbb{Q}_p}(\sigma(x))^{1/d_L} = \iota(N_{K/\Bbb{Q}}(x))^{1/d_K}
$$
where $d_L = [L : \Bbb{Q}_p]$ and $d_K = [K : \Bbb{Q}]$?

Comment: You must assume $[L:\mathbf Q_p] = [K:\mathbf Q]$. After all, take $x= 2$ in the equation you want and see what that tells you. If $p$ is inert in $K$ then $L$ is the completion of $K$ at the unique prime in $K$ lying over $p$ and you get the desired equality (e.g., $K = \mathbf Q(i)$, $p=3$, and $L = \mathbf Q_3(i)$. The two norms both have the effect $x+yi \mapsto x^2+y^2$, for $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbf Q$ or $\mathbf Q_3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Consider $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and let $p\equiv 1 \bmod 4$, so that $i\in \mathbb{Q}_p$. Take $L=\mathbb{Q}_p$, and $\sigma: K\to \mathbb{Q}_p$ an embedding. Let $\alpha=3$. Then, $\iota(N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha))=\iota(9)=9$, but $$N_{L/\mathbb{Q}_p}(\sigma(3))=N_{L/\mathbb{Q}_p}(3)=3,$$
because $3\in L=\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: I see. Can the statement be fixed with an appropriate exponent depending only on $K$ and $L$? For example something like $$N_{L/\Bbb{Q}_p}(\sigma(x))^{1/d_L} = \iota(N_{K/\Bbb{Q}}(x))^{1/d_K}$$ where $d_L = [L : \Bbb{Q}_p]$ and $d_K = [K : \Bbb{Q}]$?

Comment: Take $\alpha = 1+i$ and you encounter serious problems with the formula above. I don't see a way to fix this.