# Is every non-archimedean absolute value on a number field equivalent to a $|\cdot|_{\mathfrak{p}}$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, absolute-value

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field, i.e. a finite field extension of $\Bbb{Q}$. I would like to prove that every non-archimedean absolute value on $K$ is equivalent to
$$
|x|_{\mathfrak{p}} := N_K(\mathfrak{p})^{-\text{ord}_{\mathfrak{p}}(x)}
$$
for some prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $\mathcal{O}_K$, where $|0|_\mathfrak{p} = 0$ by convention and otherwise $\text{ord}_{\mathfrak{p}}(x)$ is the exponent of $\mathfrak{p}$ in the prime factorization of $(x)$, and where $N_K(\mathfrak{p}) = |\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}|$ is the absolute norm of $\mathfrak{p}$.

**Preliminary question:** Is this actually true?

If so, how can I prove this? I know that the completion of $K$ with respect to a non-archimedean absolute value is isomorphic to a finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ for some prime number $p$, and that
$$
|x|_p = |N_{L/\Bbb{Q}_p}(x)|_p^{1/[L:\Bbb{Q}_p]}
$$
is the unique extension of $|\cdot|_p$ to a finite extension $L$ of $\Bbb{Q}_p$, but I don't know how to conclude from here.

See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330434/does-the-field-norm-commute-with-field-morphisms) related question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is true. The case for $\mathbb{Q}$ is sometimes called [Ostrowski's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski's_theorem), although related results also go by this name. The proof for number fields is extremely similar (and sometimes *also* called Ostrowski's Theorem).

A complete proof can be found [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/ostrowski.pdf). It is not very long.

---

Some additional (more reputable) references per request:

In Chapter 2.1 of Silverman's [The Arithmetic of Dynamical Systems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387699031), Ostrowski's Theorem is given. [Incidentally, I learned this fact from him]. But it's given without proof. For proofs, he references Theorem 3, 1.4.2, of [Number Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0121178501) by Borevich and Shafarevich or Theorem 1, I.2, of Koblitz's [p-adic Numbers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387960171) book. I haven't read either of these, but I do not doubt Silverman.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of a textbook or another resource that I can cite which contains that proof?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include some hardened references that I know

Comment: I checked those references. Sadly, (just like every other reference I was able to find) they mention only the version of Ostrowski's theorem for $\Bbb{Q}$. I don't see any immediate way to derive the version for $K \supset \Bbb{Q}$ from that one, though.