# Inequality for absolute value of number field norm

Tags: inequality, algebraic-number-theory

Let $k$ be a number field, which we think as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and let $|\!\cdot\!|$ be the absolute value of $\mathbb{C}$. Further, write $N_k$ for the norm of $k$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and put $n = [k : \mathbb{Q}]$.

Is it true that $|N_k(a + b)|^{1/n} \leq |N_k(a)|^{1/n} + |N_k(b)|^{1/n}$ for all $a,b \in k$ ?

If so, where can I find a reference or a short proof for this fact?

I believe that inequality should be true because I remember that $|N_k(\cdot)|^{1/n}$ is used to extend an absolute value on $\mathbb{Q}$ to $k$, or something similar...

Thanks.

Comment: This is not true. 

There might be an easier example than mine, but here it is. Let $K = \Bbb Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3)$.
We have
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{N}_{K / \Bbb Q}(2+\sqrt 3 - \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 6) &= -191\\
\mathrm{N}_{K / \Bbb Q}(2+\sqrt 3) &= 1\\
\mathrm{N}_{K / \Bbb Q}(- \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 6)&=16
\end{align*}
but 
$191^{1/4} \simeq 3.7$ is not smaller than $1^{1/4} + 16^{1/4}=3$.

Comment: This is true if you work with local fields $L / \Bbb Q_p$. Namely, the map
$|\mathrm{N}_{L / \Bbb Q_p}( \cdot )|_p^{1/[L : \Bbb Q_p]}$ defines a non-archimedean absolute value on $L$, so that the triangle inequality holds.

If $p \in \Bbb Z$ is a prime inert in $K$, then the completion $L:=K_P$ of $K$ at the unique prime $P$ of $K$ above $p$ is an extension of $K$ of degree $n = [K : \Bbb Q](=efr=f)$, and we should have 
$
\mathrm{N}_{K_P/\Bbb{Q}_p}\Big\vert_K = 
\mathrm{N}_{K/\Bbb{Q}}
$
as mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330434).

Comment: Therefore you might get something like $|\mathrm{N}_{K / \Bbb Q}( a+b )|_p^{1/n} \leq |\mathrm{N}_{K / \Bbb Q}( a )|_p^{1/n}  + |\mathrm{N}_{K / \Bbb Q}( b )|_p^{1/n}$.

In my above example, the extension $K / \Bbb Q$ is Galois but not cyclic, so you cannot find any inert prime anyway.